# The uses of 'very' as an emphatic word

Tags: emphasis

I have found a sentence in a text in which the word 'very' works as an emphatic word. The sentence is: "These very habits should be formed in student life." The word 'very' emphasizes the noun 'habits' here. I have found this types of emphasizing first. So, I don't know so much about it. Please someone make me understand how 'very' works as an emphatic word. When, where and how can I use it in sentences? Please make me clear about it.

Comment: _very_ is an adjective in that sentence and qualifies _habits._ It emphasizes _habits_ as you yourself have pointed out. I dunno what else you want to know. Check a dictionary maybe to find more such usages of _very._

Comment: Singular "this" and plural "habits" are incompatible. It should be either the singular NP "this very habit" or the plural "these very habits".

Comment: The comments are valid and the closure is reasonable and not insulting to the questioner. The downvote is mere unkindness that, without explanation, merely deters newcomers. I suggest the vote be retracted or explained. This is not the way to encourage people to enjoy our language. Read the Code of Conduct and consider the harm you do by unsubstantiated negativity.

Comment: I have therefore removed the downvote by upvoting what is a reasonable (although imperfectly posed) question.